# android - FileProvider - name must not be empty

Tags: android

I have the following FileProvider in my manifest :

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.android.provider.DataSharing-1"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths"/>

    </provider>
```

I am getting the following exception on app launch :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name must not be empty
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name must not be empty
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.addRoot(FileProvider.java:644)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:587)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:534)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.attachInfo(FileProvider.java:352)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4790) ...
```

How do I resolve this ? Where did I miss specifying a name ?

Edit :

res/xml/paths.xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <files-path android:name="my_images" android:path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a valid authority name (the `-1` gives me pause). However, I think your real problem is in the metadata -- post `res/xml/paths.xml`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do I need to post how I am using FileProvider in code ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried removing the '-1'. It still has the same problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the `android:` prefix from the attributes in your `paths.xml` file. It should look like:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

(and you can probably get rid of the `xmlns:android` bit too, since it's not used, though I have it in [one of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider/res/xml/provider_paths.xml), perhaps because Eclipse put it there when creating the file...)

Comment: Previosuly, I had the 'name' and 'path' as you said. But then I got the error : Android attribute is missing namespace prefix.

Comment: Okay it worked. I removed the xmlns.. as well as the 'android:' in path and name. Thanks !

Comment: @Jake hwo does ur paths.xml look? i am stuck with the same

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me . So i closed the project from Android Studio and then deleted .gradle and .idea files and then it started working like a charm :) First it was an issue with the authorities. you should give the .fileprovider or the fileprovider for your app maybe with the applicationId and then it works. Hope this might help someone

Answer (score 0):

In my case the xml file was saved as filename_V21.xml that created the problem. I renamed the path file to filename.xml solved the problem.